# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "answer": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * from contacts where ans answer

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The error I'm facing is

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "answer": syntax error
>   (code 1), while compiling: SELECT  * from contacts where ans answer.

```
 public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT  * from contacts where ans " + CONTACTS_COLUMN_ANS, null );
        return res;
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to select from your DB. In any case, your SQL query is invalid

Answer (score 1):

If your function is right then **Rectify** your Query . Missing to set `=` sign .

You can try with

```
  Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM "+ contacts + " WHERE " + ans + " = '"+ CONTACTS_COLUMN_ANS +"'" , null );
```

Comment: @Rotwang okay sir

Answer (score 1):

You can use like..

```
String[] params = new String[]{ contact_no };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ans = ?",
                   params);
```

Comment: this is one of the best option to avoid mistakes for int and text values using string arrays

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  public Cursor getData() 
  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM "+ contacts + " WHERE " + ans + " = '"+ CONTACTS_COLUMN_ANS +"'" , null );
    return res;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code with this

```
 public Cursor getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from contacts where ans='" +CONTACTS_COLUMN_ANS + "'", null );
    return res;
}
```